# How do I make my <div> the full height of a page?

Tags: css, html, height

I just made a 100% height div on this page, but (at least in Chrome and Chromium), there are slight top and bottom margins. I want to have the div cover those, but I don't want to resort to using to a specified height, as I'll be using the same set-up across multiple pages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do your html, body and div elements all have border:0 and margin:0?

Comment: All better. Just had to set my body's margin and border to 0.

Answer (score 2):

Set border, margin and padding to 0.